# Visual Studio 2010 Release Canidate Model Project

Tags: visual-studio, modeling

I just moved from Visual Studio 2010 beta 2 to Visual Studio 2010 Release Candidate RC.

My beta 2 solution included a modeling project.

Visual Studio 2010 Release Candidate would not open the modeling project created in beta 2.

I created a new modeling project in VS2010 RC and added the activity diagrams, class diagrams, and sequence diagrams from the beta 2 modeling project.

VS2010 RC will not open the beta2 modeling files...
Unsupported version '0.3.0.0', can only support '1.0.0.0'.

Is there a project converter available?

Comment: Cameron Skinner blogged about modeling project migration to RC...
'if you have created modeling projects and diagrams in the beta2 build, we will be providing a tool that will automatically upgrade those files / artifacts to the RC build, when available. We’ll be announcing that tool very soon after the RC build announced.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Architecture Model Upgrade Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/eb401aac-2926-4043-b355-7d2ede848541) has been made available to upgrade modeling projects created in VS2010 beta 2 to VS2010 RC.

Answer (score 0):

There's no converter out *yet*.  **But**, the RC has just been available since yesterday and only to MSDN subscribers, tomorrow it's public.  There's a much higher chance you'll find something in the next week or so.